# How to make all the gem classes and modules private?

Tags: ruby

How it is possible to only expose one module or a class from a Ruby gem and close everything else?

For example, in a `my-math` library, I only want to expose `Math` module, but not any other, such as `Math::Utils` or similar.

I want to enforce one and only one way of using the gem.

At least making it hard to access internal classes will help (even munging the names at runtime will be better than open-access).

Comment: Are the ones you want to hide all within the namespace of a certain module?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to make them private, or inaccessible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not clear what you are trying to do, but if you want private constants, why not just declare them as so?

```
module Namespace
  module Secret
  end
  private_constant :Secret
  Secret # => Namespace::Secret
end

Namespace::Secret # => NameError. Private constant Namespace::Secret referenced.
```

Comment: Yeah, making private. That should do the job, thanks!